# Raspberry PI multi-threaded socket issue C

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets, raspberry-pi

so i have a very basic tcp server which has two threads listening on two separate ports. However, when the code runs the second thread is never created and it appears that the first thread is actually blocking the whole program from creating the next thread. Here is the code... (quite simple)

```
void *Listener1();
void *Listener2();

int main()
{
    pthread_t thread1, thread2;
    pthread_create(&thread1, NULL,Listener1(), NULL);
    pthread_create(&thread2, NULL,Listener2(), NULL);
    sleep(50);
    return 0;
}
void *Listener1()
{
     int sockfd, newsockfd;
     socklen_t clilen;
     struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;

     sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
     if (sockfd < 0) 
        puts("ERROR opening socket");
     bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
     serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
     serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
     serv_addr.sin_port = htons(12346);
     if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,
              sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) 
              puts("ERROR on binding");
     listen(sockfd,1);
     clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);

     newsockfd = accept(sockfd, 
                 (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, 
                 &clilen);
     if (newsockfd < 0) 
          puts("ERROR on accept");
     else
        puts("Client connected!");

     close(newsockfd);
     close(sockfd);
     return 0; 
}
void *Listener2()
{
    puts("hi)");
     int sockfd, newsockfd;
     socklen_t clilen;
     struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;

     sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
     if (sockfd < 0) 
        puts("ERROR opening socket");
     bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
     serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
     serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
     serv_addr.sin_port = htons(12345);
     if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,
              sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) 
              puts("ERROR on binding");
     listen(sockfd,1);
     clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);
     newsockfd = accept(sockfd, 
                 (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, 
                 &clilen);
     if (newsockfd < 0) 
          puts("ERROR on accept");
     else
        puts("Client connected!");

     close(newsockfd);
     close(sockfd);
     return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cake a close look at

```
pthread_create(&thread1, NULL,Listener1(), NULL);
//                                     ^^
//                           causes the function to be called
```

Here you don't pass a pointer to the `Listener1` function, you are actually *calling* it, and its returned value would be used as the function pointer to the thread function, if it ever returned.

You should instead pass a pointer to the function:

```
pthread_create(&thread1, NULL,&Listener1, NULL);
```